# Show Padding Under Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`. I have added the style `overflow: auto` to the div - this makes it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9lKS.png)

My question is: how do I add space under the content - like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssONC.png) (as you can see, there's a space under the text - I made this using paint.

My code is:

```
<div class="background" style="overflow: auto;">
<h2>ABOUT</h2>
<p>And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an example</p>
</div>
```

Comment: reverse your condition.

Comment: hello????????????????????????????

Comment: add a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if rows are returned so if rows are > 0, simply change

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($pendingrequests )==0) {
```

to

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($pendingrequests ) > 0) {
```